# Flutter FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage & Nearby not working together on same isolate

Tags: flutter, firebase, background, isolate

I am using FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage for calling message notification etc and Nearby for WifiDirect when I run both together Nearby unable to find nearby users but as soon as i comment the FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage it works perfectly. they both use method channel and unable to run on same main isolate is there any solution or suggestion how can i solve this

[Nearby](https://pub.dev/packages/nearby_connections)
[Firebase Message](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging)